# Run-time stack terminology

Tags: c, memory-model

When talking about allocation and deallocation of the run-time stack do pop and deallocate have the same meaning and push and allocate have the same meaning?

Is,

Deallocation from the run-time stack takes place in the following order:

1. Deallocation of the local variables
2. Pop return address and use to determine next instruction
3. Deallocate parameters
4. Pop returned value and use as specified in calling statement

Equivalent to,

Deallocation from the run-time stack takes place in the following order:

1. Pop the local variables
2. Pop the return address and use to determine next instruction
3. Pop the parameters
4. Pop the returned value and use as specified in calling statement

Comment: Yes. Those words are just synonyms in this case.

Comment: Yes, no, maybe.  In the context of C, there isn't much difference.  If the context were C++, the 'deallocate' part would be significantly different from the 'pop' part — destructors would be run.

Comment: "stack" is an implementation specific detail and at a very abstract level, what you described is true. But that doesn't have to true on all implementations or follow the exact steps. For example, arguments can be passed via registers, entire stack frame be "destroyed" in a single step (rather than reclaiming individual parts) etc - in many ways it can differ from what you have described.

Comment: Although this is a fun question, it will have many different answers from the people here, and is just as easily answered with online tutorials, such as this one:  _[Explain Run-time Stack in C Programming with Examples](http://www.sanfoundry.com/c-question-run-time-stack-usage/)_

Comment: Fun fact: the word "stack" appears _nowhere_ in the text of the 1999 C standard.  There is a requirement to support recursive function calls, but how that is done is left completely up to the implementation.  (C2011 may have had to add something about stacks as part of the thread spec, I haven't checked.)